# URL routing with query string

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have a problem with url routing with query string.

Global.asax code

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add("Mycity", new Route("Mycity/{cityname}",
 new PageRouteHandler("~/Default.aspx")));
```

default.aspx code

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server"  NavigateUrl='<%$RouteUrl:RouteName=Mycity,cityname=Eval("cityname")%>'>
```

city_name is sqldata table coulmn name
Eval("city_name")

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an inline code tag (<%%>) in an asp.net control attribute.

You need to bind it in the codebehind (page_load)

```
this.HyperLink1.NavigateUrl =  "/virt_dir/Mycity/YOUR_CITYNAME";
```